# Difference between string.equalsIgnoreCase(object.string) vs object.string.equalsIgnoreCase(string)

Tags: java, string, class, object

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class MyClass {
    String locale;

    public String getLocale(){
        return this.locale;
    }

    public setLocale(String locale){
        this.locale = locale;
    }
}
```

Now I have been told that there is a difference in following statements

1. `myClass.getLocale().equalsIgnoreCase("en")`
2. `("en").equalsIgnoreCase(myClass.getLocale())`

I have been trying to find the search for it but unable to do so. Can anyone help me with an explanation of what is the difference?

Is there a particular difference in execution time? And also which of these two is the best practice

Comment: just typed it while writing .. didnt copy the actual code

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvotes, i'd like to improve the question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)` javadoc states :

> Compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations.
>   Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same
>   length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal
>   ignoring case.

So the behavior of these statements is the same as `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)` produces the same result whichever is the `String` invoker and the `String` argument as far as these are not `null`.

The single thing that could differ is the presence of `null` references in the statements that could provoke the throw of `NullPointerException`.
In your example, the two statements may trow `NullPointerException` but not at the same places :

```
myClass.getLocale().equalsIgnoreCase("en")
    |-----|---- two potential NPE

("en").equalsIgnoreCase(myClass.getLocale())
                            |----- potential NPE
```

Note that the second way is more robust as it will fail only if `myClass` is `null` while the first may fail for either `myClass` or `myClass.getLocale()` refer to `null`.

To conclude, if in your application `myClass` cannot be `null` you should stick to the second way.
Otherwise if `myClass` may be `null` you should perform a `null` check before :

```
boolean isEqualIgnoreCase = false;
if (myClass != null){
   isEqualIgnoreCase = ("en").equalsIgnoreCase(myClass.getLocale());
}
```

Comment: Understood, can you also let me know that according to you which one is the preferred solution

Comment: It depends on your application . I updated to give hints about which way should be favored according to the case.

Answer (score 1):

`myClass.getLocale().equalsIgnoreCase("en")` throws `NullPointerException` when `myClass.locale` is null.

`("en").equalsIgnoreCase(myClass.getLocale())` does not compile.

If you are talking about `"en".equalsIgnoreCase(myClass.getLocale())`, it works fine when `myClass.locale` is null. `false` will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I spot is that in the first example the statement `myClass.getLocale()` is not null-safe, thus somehow might return `null` and it would lead to the NullPointerException.

The second one is safe since you call a method on `"en"`, which is never `null` and will not fail even if you pass a `null` to the method with `myClass.getLocale()`.

---

Edit: Both of the explanations assume that the `myClass` is not null itself, thus only `getLocale()` would fail. Noone of the solutions is null-safe in case the `myClass` is null - then the NPE will be thrown anyway. (@davidxxx)

Comment: Ok so according to your knowledge .. other than the null pointer .. the code is fine as in there is no execution time changes or anything correct?

Comment: The only difference is what you compare with. The second one will never throw the NPE, but the first one theoretically can. There is no other difference indeed.

Comment: Could someone explain the downvote since I am not aware of any mistake. Feel free to correct me and give me a feedback, which is better.

Comment: Understood and also can you let me know which one is the preferred way of coding? I dont know who downvoted lol... all the answers each had the downvote

Comment: @Nikolas Not the downvoter (you have my vote) but note that the second one will  throw a NPE if MyClass is null. Just not at the same place. No one of these statements perform the required null check to avoid NPE.

Comment: @davixxx: Thank you very much. Now I see my answer is a bit unclear. I explicitly said that `myClass.getLocale()` might result in null, but I didn' mention the fact that `myClass` can be `null` itself which will throw NPE anyway.